# Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly on Android Studio 4.2

Tags: android-studio, gradle

[image]I encountered "Gradle project sync failed" on Android Studio 4.2 and some of the class members are mostly red. I have done some troubleshooting as below.

1. File->Sync Project with Gradle Files
2. File-> invalidates caches/restart
3. Restart Android Studio
4. Clean and Rebuild
5. Try deleting .gradle

However, the problem still persists. What went wrong actually?

Trace logfiles:

```
2021-05-12 17:50:44,928 [24467617]   WARN - ues.SyncIssueUsageReporterImpl - Multiple sync failures reported. Discarding: SDK_BUILD_TOOLS_TOO_LOW 
2021-05-12 17:50:44,928 [24467617]   WARN - ues.SyncIssueUsageReporterImpl - Multiple sync failures reported. Discarding: SDK_BUILD_TOOLS_TOO_LOW 
2021-05-12 17:50:44,929 [24467618]   INFO - adleSyncState$SyncStateUpdater - onFailure(RESOLVE_PROJECT:5, com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.) 
2021-05-12 17:50:44,929 [24467618]   INFO - cState$SyncStateUpdaterService - stopTrackingTask(RESOLVE_PROJECT:5) 
2021-05-12 17:50:44,929 [24467618]   WARN - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. (3 s 326 ms) 
2021-05-12 17:50:44,930 [24467619]   WARN - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(GradleExecutionErrorHandler.java:153)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.doGetUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:181)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:45)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.checkErrorsWithoutQuickFixes(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:59)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$1.getUserFriendlyError(GradleProjectResolver.java:798)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:720)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.lambda$execute$0(GradleExecutionHelper.java:128)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleConnectorService.withGradleConnection(GradleConnectorService.java:246)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:114)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:142)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:64)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:46)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:102)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:147)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:133)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.executeImpl(ExternalSystemUtil.java:523)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.lambda$execute$1(ExternalSystemUtil.java:372)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceHeavyActivities.suspendIndexingAndRun(DumbServiceHeavyActivities.java:20)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.suspendIndexingAndRun(DumbServiceImpl.java:153)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:372)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:631)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:935)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsync$5(CoreProgressManager.java:442)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$null$3(ProgressRunner.java:235)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:629)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:581)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:60)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:235)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
```

Answer (score 2):

I had faced the same problem.

**Solution:**

If your Android Studio version is 4.2.2 and your app contains more than one modules then make sure to **keep the targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion as same for all your build.gradle files**(including your modules).

Comment: I need a help. Can you explain this where I should check for this. I checked app level gradle file and it is OK. anywhere else?

Answer (score 1):

I have just experienced this issue seemingly out of thin air, and found the cause:

I updated the google play services ads module to:
`api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.1.0'`

This causes the gradle sync to fail.
Looking into the IDEA log I found the line `com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.issues.SdkPlatformNotFoundException: Module: 'my-module' platform 'android-28' not found.`

So I updated `my-module` to use the `targetSdkVersion 29` and the build works again.

Comment: Thanks...Yes, I did upgrade mymodule to targetSdkVersion 29. However, It still gets stuck on the Gradle project sync failed
2021-05-12 09:49:04,807 [57078920]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from D:/Android studio/jre 
2021-05-12 09:49:04,809 [57078922]   INFO - ativeWorkspaceModificationTask - NDK support for project 'Android_CrowdSourcing' is disabled because the project doesn't contain any valid native configurations.

Comment: @Reyha Can you upload your log file somewhere? (Help -> Show log in Files). Run the gradle sync again before copying the file. For me, the cause for the error was logged some lines above the most recent line.

Comment: Please see the above logfiles

Comment: I've found the solution. I downgraded my Android Studio from 4.2 to 4.1.2 version and no such error. Thanks McFarlane

Comment: @Reyha: "SDK_BUILD_TOOLS_TOO_LOW" looks like the actual warning. Downgrading your AS will not help, if you plan to use update the Studio some other time. One line of the log is not enough to determine the error, though. Also, please upload and link the logfile, instead of posting it unformatted.

Answer (score 0):

Please Downgrade Studio Version to 4.1.3

Currently, 4.2.* versions are having the significant number of issues.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe need to upgrade or downgrade your "targetSdkVersion"
i experienced the same issue and the solution was upgrading my "targetSdkVersion"